# python list/sequence formatting

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have a list of lists in the format like below.

[[1,3],[2,4],[3,1],[4,0],[5,1],[6,0],[7,1],[8,0],[9,1],[10,0],[11,3],[12,1],[13,0],[14,1],[15,0],[16,1],[17,0],[18,4],[19,1],[20,0],[21,1],[22,0],[23,1],[24,2],[25,0],[26,0],[27,1],[28,0].........]

or in graphically manner my input list is:

```
[1,3]
    [2,4]
        [3,1]
            [4,0]
        [5,1]
            [6,0]
        [7,1]
            [8,0]
        [9,1]
            [10,0]
    [11,3]
        [12,1]
            [13,0]
        [14,1]
            [15,0]
        [16,1]
            [17,0]
    [18,4]
        [19,1]
            [20,0]
        [21,1]
            [22,0]
        [23,1]
            [24,2]
                [25,0]
                [26,0]
        [27,1]
            [28,0]
```

In above input, first value(zero position) of list is item sequence( as you can see them in from top to bottom), second value is number of child it has!

I want my output that in third value(2nd position) i want its parent like in example as below.. .

and i want to get output like:
[[1,3,0],[2,4,1],[3,1,2],[4,0,3],[5,1,2],[6,0,5],[7,1,2],[8,0,7],[9,1,2],[10,0,9],[11,3,1],[12,1,11],[13,0,12],[14,1,11],[15,0,14],[16,1,11],[17,0,16],[18,4,1],[19,1,18],[20,0,19],[21,1,18],[22,0,21],[23,1,18],[24,2,23],[25,0,24],[26,0,24],[27,1,18],[28,0,27].....]

desired output in graphical way:

```
[1,3,0]
    [2,4,1]
        [3,1,2]
            [4,0,3]
        [5,1,2]
            [6,0,5]
        [7,1,2]
            [8,0,7]
        [9,1,2]
            [10,0,9]
    [11,3,1]
        [12,1,11]
            [13,0,12]
        [14,1,11]
            [15,0,14]
        [16,1,11]
            [17,0,16]
    [18,4,1]
        [19,1,18]
            [20,0,19]
        [21,1,18]
            [22,0,21]
        [23,1,18]
            [24,2,23]
                [25,0,24]
                [26,0,24]
        [27,1,18]
            [28,0,27]
```

how can it be solved?

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a directly usable example. AFAICT this would be as easy as removing the dots in your example - but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with an iterator like this:

```
def add_parent_info(it, parent=0):
    me, num_children = it.next() # For Python 3.x use next(it)
    yield [me, num_children, parent]
    for i in range(num_children):
        for item in add_parent_info(it, me):
            yield item
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = [[1,3],[2,4],[3,1],[4,0],[5,1],[6,0],[7,1],[8,0],[9,1],[10,0],[11,3],[12,1],[13,0],[14,1],[15,0],[16,1],[17,0],[18,4],[19,1],[20,0],[21,1],[22,0],[23,1],[24,2],[25,0],[26,0],[27,1],[28,0]]
>>> print list(add_parent_info(iter(a)))
[[1, 3, 0], [2, 4, 1], [3, 1, 2], [4, 0, 3], [5, 1, 2], [6, 0, 5], [7, 1, 2], [8, 0, 7], [9, 1, 2], [10, 0, 9], [11, 3, 1], [12, 1, 11], [13, 0, 12], [14, 1, 11], [15, 0, 14], [16, 1, 11], [17, 0, 16], [18, 4, 1], [19, 1, 18], [20, 0, 19], [21, 1, 18], [22, 0, 21], [23, 1, 18], [24, 2, 23], [25, 0, 24], [26, 0, 24], [27, 1, 18], [28, 0, 27]]
```

Comment: +1 I was trying to do something like this with iterators but wasn't sure how to go about doing it. Had to clutter my code with returning the current index on items :(

Comment: open/restart a new python shell, i think you must have created a `list` and called it `'list'`. eg. `list = [1,2,3]`. That is never a good idea as you are losing functionality to the `list` class by replacing it with a variable.

Comment: +1, this is the same way I solved it. @user1283171, works fine for me, what version of Python are you using? can you post the traceback?

Comment: After restarting python shell... it worked!!!
Also i am posting my original work where i need it!!!

Answer (score 1):

edit: @WolframH has the best solution for generating the structure.  You can combine his elegant solution with the Node object structure by altering `__init__` to be:

```
def __init__(self,value,parent_value,child_value,list_of_children):
    self.value=value
    self.parent_value = parent_value
    self.child_value = child_value
    self.children = list_of_children
```

Use @WolframH 's method of generating the structure, and walk through all the entries calling the Node constructor on it. That way, you could more readably insert and remove items.

---

You would need to define a data structure (a tree comes to mind) and store the values in it. I would suggest using a tree, applying the node class down the tree. (you could define a different format called leaf, but wouldn't really make a difference.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val,list_of_children,parent_value)
        self.value = val
        self.children = make_children(list_of_children,val)
        self.parent_value = parent_value

    # in case number of children changes, don't generate middle value
    # until necessary
    def get_list_of_values(self):
        [self.value,len(children),self.parent_value]

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def change_value(self,new_value):
        """update children to reflect changed value"""
        self.value = new_value
        def fn(child):
            child.parent_value = new_value
        map(fn,self.children)


def make_children(list_of_children,parent_value):
    child_list=[]
    # recursive-ish case: there are children
    if list_of_children:
        for child in list_of_children:
            # presuming initially stored as list of lists, e.g. 
            #    [node_value,[node[leaf][leaf]],[node,[node[leaf]],[leaf]]
            #    so child[0] is value, and rest are children
            value = child.pop(0)
            child_list.append(Node(value,child,parent_value)))
        return child_list
    # base case: no children - so return empty set
    else:
        return []
```

Comment: Note: this assumes there isn't a sorting function for children. If there is, you could define it, make it into a decorator, and decorate make_children with it.

Comment: also, if you want to be able to change parents, it would be simple: just change the self.parent_value over all the children.  e.g. `map(lambda child: child.parent_value = new_value, list_of_children)`

Comment: I am getting error as: "lambda cannot contain assignment"! 

My python version is 2.7.2

Comment: A `lambda` can only contain an expression.  Assignment is a statement!  So, just define an actual function with `def` and then pass the name of the function in to `map()`.

Comment: I keep forgetting that fact about lambdas, I'm used to Scheme where there's no difference between lambda and named methods (plus it was kinda late when I answered :P)

Comment: Updated the answer appropriately  @WolframH definitely has the best solution for creating the list. This lets you maintain and update the structure.

Answer (score 1):

@WolframH has the best solution using iterators, i'll just leave this here as an inefficient example without using iterators :D

```
>>> stuff = [[1,3],[2,4],[3,1],[4,0],[5,1],[6,0],[7,1],[8,0],[9,1],[10,0],[11,3],[12,1],[13,0],[14,1],[15,0],[16,1],[17,0],[18,4],[19,1],[20,0],[21,1],[22,0],[23,1],[24,2],[25,0],[26,0],[27,1],[28,0]]
>>> def walk(parent, i, items):
        item_seq, num_children = items[i]
        children = [items[i]+[parent]]
        for _ in range(num_children):
            i,child = walk(item_seq,i+1,items)
            children.extend(child)
        return i, children

>>> walk(0,0,stuff)[1]
[[1, 3, 0], [2, 4, 1], [3, 1, 2], [4, 0, 3], [5, 1, 2], [6, 0, 5], [7, 1, 2], [8, 0, 7], [9, 1, 2], [10, 0, 9], [11, 3, 1], [12, 1, 11], [13, 0, 12], [14, 1, 11], [15, 0, 14], [16, 1, 11], [17, 0, 16], [18, 4, 1], [19, 1, 18], [20, 0, 19], [21, 1, 18], [22, 0, 21], [23, 1, 18], [24, 2, 23], [25, 0, 24], [26, 0, 24], [27, 1, 18], [28, 0, 27]]
```

Comment: yup its working. . but still we can reduce the code length!!!
You effort is appreciable..
Thanks,

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure how to reduce the code length any more, i've removed the x and while loop and changed it into a for loop which has removed two lines from it.

Comment: Actually I managed to shorten it more, hope that is good enough I'm not sure if i can shorten it any more now!

Comment: from "while" to "for", and now the current one.

but let others try and see if anyone else can come up with different and better answer!!! and about your work.. . Great!!!!!

Comment: @WolframH has the best solution

Comment: Are you talking about my solution or @WolframH? If you are talking about his you should add comment to his post.